# How do I annotate my graph using JUNG's annotation system?

Tags: java, swing, jung

I cannot seem to find any documentation on annotating my JUNG graph. The most I've cobbled together is:

```
AnnotationRenderer renderer = new AnnotationRenderer();
AnnotationPaintable annotate = new AnnotationPaintable(viewer.getRenderContext(), renderer);

Shape square = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
Annotation<Shape> a = new Annotation<Shape>(square, Annotation.Layer.UPPER, null, true,
                new Point2D.Double(0, 0));
annotate.add(a);
```

How do I take this and start drawing the actual annotations within the AnnotationPaintable object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to add it to your visualization viewer:

```
viewer.addPostRenderPaintable(...)
```

Comment: True but sometimes you may also need to do `viewer.addPreRenderPaintable(...)` because `PostRendererPaintable` will make annotation appear on the foreground before the vertices (regardless of the `Annotation.Layer.UPPER` parameter), and it may not be something that everybody wants.